# Session lost when closed then reopened

Tags: php, apache

I have written a PHP script that, when I run on my local computer/server with the standard configuration, retains a SESSION but does not when I run it on another server.

The code I'm running:

```
function dump_session() {
  echo "\$_SESSION:";
  var_dump($_SESSION);
}

session_start();
echo "Session name: " . session_name() . "\n";

dump_session();

echo "Close session\n";
session_commit(); // using session_destroy() as same result;

echo "Start session\n";
session_start();
echo "Session name: " . session_name() . "\n";

dump_session();
```

On my local computer/server, this is the result:

```
Session name: BOPHPSESSID
$_SESSION:array(1) {
  'FOO' =>
  string(3) "BAR"
}
Close session
Start session
Session name: BOPHPSESSID
$_SESSION:array(1) {
  'FOO' =>
  string(3) "BAR"
}
```

On the other server, this is the result:

```
Session name: BOPHPSESSID
$_SESSION:array(1) {
  'FOO' =>
  string(3) "BAR"
}
Close session
Start session
Session name: BOPHPSESSID
$_SESSION:array(0) {
}
```

Why is `$_SESSION` cleared on the other server? Is there something in the php.ini configuration that could cause this?

Comment: session_destroy. try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you need to use `session_destroy();`

[From the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

You can also use unset() for individual session variables.

Answer (score 0):

To destroy the session in php you need to use session_destroy or unset(). Before using these, make sure the session is set by doing: if(isset($_SESSION['sessionName']))